# Python 3 urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, exception, httprequest, urllib, python-3.4

How can I avoid exceptions from `urllib.request.urlopen` if `response.status_code` is not 200? Now it raise `URLError` or `HTTPError` based on request status.

Is there any other way to make request with python3 basic libs?

How can I get response headers if `status_code != 200` ?

Comment: I dont understand, if there is an error opening the url what do you want to receive?

Comment: Can you give us some code to explain what you're doing?

Comment: @lapinkoira the question is legit, the fact that a webpage returned HTTP 400 mean the the HTTP has error, but it's not a programmatic error, and in some cases you would to read everything (response code, payload, headers) without an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 33):

Use `try except`, the below code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
req = Request("http://www.111cn.net /")
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    # do something
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    # do something
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    # do something
    print('good!')
```

Comment: So how can I get headers in this case?

Answer (score 8):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError) state that the exception type, `HTTPError`, can also be treated as a `HTTPResponse`. Thus, you can get the response body from an error response as follows:

```py
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

def open_url(request):
  try:
    return urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    # "e" can be treated as a http.client.HTTPResponse object
    return e
```

and then use as follows:

```py
result = open_url('http://www.stackoverflow.com/404-file-not-found')
print(result.status)           # prints 404
print(result.read())           # prints page contents
print(result.headers.items())  # lists headers
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from py3 docs

```
>>> import http.client
>>> conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
>>> # Example of an invalid request
>>> conn.request("GET", "/parrot.spam")
>>> r2 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print(r2.status, r2.reason)
404 Not Found
>>> data2 = r2.read()
>>> conn.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples